# Personalize Diff Command in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, console, diff

I have two files, both with a lot of data, what I need is compare the first word of each file  (each file always starts with a number, and each number could have many digits).

The files are identical when these numbers are the same.

Example:
I have 3 files: a.txt, b.txt and c.txt

```
 a.txt content is "1 a b c 3 5 6 hjkj"
 b.txt content is "1 c f a 1234 h"
 c.txt content is "2 a b c 3 5 6 hjkj"

 diff a.txt b.txt should return "files are identical"
 diff a.txt c.txt should return "files are different"
```

How can I compare them using the diff command?

Comment: please update question with some example input. Makes it a lot easier for us to provide a good answer when we don't have to guess :-)

Comment: do you know how many digit has this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to check if the 1st "word" of the files match.  This shell function should do that.

```
check_first_word(){
  read FIRST GARBAGE < $1
  read SECOND GARBAGE < $2
  [ "$FIRST" == "$SECOND" ] && echo "files are identical" || echo "files are different"
}
```

usage:

```
check_first_word file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `awk`.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'FNR==1 { if(NR==1) a=$1; else b=$1 } END { if(a==b) print "files are identical"; else print "files are different" }' $1 $2
```

Store above command in file named `mydiff`, give executable permission using `chmod +x` and then you can execute personalized *diff* command as follows

```
mydiff file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job, put this function in your bashrc file.

```
function mydiff() {
       DIGITS=10
       file_1=`head -c ${DIGITS} $1`
       file_2=`head -c ${DIGITS} $2`

       if [ "$file_1" == "$file_2" ]
         then echo "Files are identical"
       else
         echo "Files are different" 
       fi
}
```

Usage :

```
mydiff file_1 file_2
```